# How does body-parser know if we sign up or log in?

Tags: node.js, ejs, body-parser

I'm building my user authentication and the tutorials don't really get into details in 100%.

The examples always show how you get logged in if you submit data, assuming it's in the database already.

But on many HTML pages, you see sign in and log in button next to each other. How can I make body parser recognize the required function depending on which button is pressed? Both cases involve submitted data after all.

Thanks a lot!

PS. I'm using EJS view engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Body parser has nothing to do with log in or sign in.

It's purpose is to parse request's body by checking request header *Content-type* and using appropriate method to parse it. For example if content is json it will use *JSON.parse* and assign the result to req.body.

The buttons could be anchors with href set to */login* or */signin* so on your server you need login and signin routes to handle each of the actions